# How to read runtime Macro in Wix

Tags: wix

I Just want to read a name from a file or read from command line after creating installer file.

I have defined a Macro in my MainProject.wxs file as

< ?define product = "xyz"?>

And I am reading the Macro "product" as follows,

< Registry Action="write"

```
              Id="RegistryEntryId"
              Name="InstallDir"
              Key="Software\$(var.product)\MyOwnName"
              Root="HKLM"
              Type="string"
              Value="[INSTALLPATH]"
              KeyPath="yes"/>
```

on build time.

But I want to define and read this "product" on runtime after the installer is created, so that I can change the product name according to the file content on runtime, any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A macro is handled by a preprocessor. What you request is a variable that can be changed at runtime. You need to use a [property](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/property.html).

```
<Property Id="PROJECTNAME">xyz</Property>
```

This property can be changed at runtime.

You read the property like this:

```
[PROJECTNAME]
```

There are different ways of changing the property. You could do that in a custom action.